# Pandas Move text in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains search results. Is it possible to move the text around in the column so that the the name is always first?

```
Results
'Phil Spencer', 'Microsoft'
'Larry Hryb', 'Microsoft'
'Microsoft', 'Bill Gates'
'Sony', 'Kenichiro, Yoshida'
'Sony', 'PS5', 'Howard Stringer'
```

Expected

```
Results
'Phil Spencer', 'Microsoft'
'Larry Hryb', 'Microsoft'
'Bill Gates', 'Microsoft'
'Kenichiro, Yoshida','Sony'
'Howard Stringer', 'Sony', 'PS5'
```

I want it so that the name is always first in the column. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: is the raw data a single column or multiple ?

Comment: its in a single column within a excel sheet

Comment: Convert it to csv and use python/pandas to read the data and switch it. Look at the pandas docs, and come back with some code here if it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a tough one, but we could assume that anything with a `space` is a name and try to order it that way.

First let's split by `,` that only proceeds after `'` and is followed by a space `\s`

---

```
s = df['Results'].str.split("',\s",expand=True).stack()

0  0           'Phil Spencer
   1             'Microsoft'
1  0             'Larry Hryb
   1             'Microsoft'
2  0              'Microsoft
   1            'Bill Gates'
3  0                   'Sony
   1    'Kenichiro, Yoshida'
4  0                   'Sony
   1                    'PS5
   2       'Howard Stringer'


new_results = (
    s.loc[s.str.contains("\s{1}").astype(int).sort_values(ascending=False).index]
    .replace({"'": "", ",": ""}, regex=True)
    .groupby(level=[0])
    .agg(", ".join)
)

0       Phil Spencer, Microsoft
1         Larry Hryb, Microsoft
2         Bill Gates, Microsoft
3       Kenichiro Yoshida, Sony
4    Howard Stringer, PS5, Sony
```

---

Another, but more computationally expensive solution would be to sort by the len of each object, but you can see this is not foolproof, as some company names may be longer than the first name.

```
(
    s.loc[s.apply(len).sort_values(ascending=False).index]
     .replace({"'": "", ",": ""}, regex=True)
    .groupby(level=[0])
    .agg(", ".join)
)

0       Phil Spencer, Microsoft
1         Microsoft, Larry Hryb # <-- wrong. 
2         Bill Gates, Microsoft
3       Kenichiro Yoshida, Sony
4    Howard Stringer, Sony, PS5
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfect. One quick question. in my DF there are other columns. How would I add new_results back into the Results column of my DF?

Comment: @Will `source_df['new_results'] = new_results` or just put it before the line of code that generates `new_results` don't forget to accept the solution if this worked for you. good luck